# How to mock methods in class under test with google test

Tags: c++, mocking, googletest

Consider this class under test:

```
class A
{
public:
    bool isTrue();
    void doSomething();
};
```

I want to test `doSomething` which calls `isTrue` in its implementation.

But I also want to set expectations on the `isTrue` method.
Is there a best practice with google test how one can mock methods of the class under test?

Comment: You could derive from class A: `class B : public A, public Mock { using A::doSomething; MOCK_METHOD0(isTrue, bool()); };`, but I think if you need to mock methods of the class under test, your class design is broken.

Comment: Yes, its legacy code and I don't like mocking own methods of the class under test either.

Comment: @arne very nice trick. but don't you need `using Mock::isTrue` in class B, instead of defining it in B? What is the point in inheriting from Mock, if you defined the method in class B?

Comment: @BЈовић Damn. No need to inherit from `Mock`. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer...

There's a little hack you can use. Define a derived class like so:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(isTrue, bool());

    using A::doSomething;
};
```

This obviously only works if `isTrue` is `virtual`.

**Beware:** Check your company's testing guidelines regarding "code made especially for testing" instead of testing the real code. In your situation (legacy codebase) this might be okay.